# Pass 2 arguments from a single file into function parameters

Tags: python, function, file

I have a function:

```
def process(fa : {str:{str:str}}, state : str, inputs : [str]) -> [None]:
```

and the parameters' (`state : str`, `inputs : [str]`) arguments would come from the file (input_file.txt) with the contents:

```
even;1;0;1;1;0;1
even;1;0;1;1;0;x
odd;1;0;1;1;0;1
```

With `state` being the first element (even/odd) and `inputs` being a list of the rest of the elements (1,0,x)

Is it possible to pass the contents from the file into the function as arguments?

I've tried comprehension but the return value is nothing near what I am trying to get, and I don't know what else to try after playing around with it for a bit:

```
proccess( fa, (item[0] for line in input_file for item in line.split(';')), (item[1:] for line in input_file for item in line.split(';') )
```

Comment: So you want to split the input into a string and a list?  Just use:  `state,*inputs=line.split(";")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
for line in open('input_file.txt','rt'):
    state,*inputs = line.strip().split(';')
    process(fa,state,inputs)
```

Comment: I see. It seems I was overcomplicating the task. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet:

```
for line in input_file for item in line.split(';')
```

returns an iterator for each element in each line:

```
even
1
0
1
1
0
1
even
1
...
```

Your `item[0]` and `item[1:]` does not result in errors because each string ("even", "1", etc) can be indexed.

You can try :

```py
proccess( fa, 
   (line.split(';')[0] for line in input_file),
   (line.split(';')[1:] for line in input_file)
)
```

By the way you should note that:

1. you are duplicating `split()` calls, and
2. if `input_file` is a file then lines only come through once, and
3. you are passing in generators not str/list of strings that the func expects.

Comment: Ahh, I see what I was doing wrong now. Thank you for the clarification!